# asyncio.sleep causes Tornado websocket to disconnect

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, tornado

We've set

```
WEBSOCKET_PING_INTERVAL_SEC = 2
WEBSOCKET_PING_TIMEOUT_SEC = 4
```

(the parameters we pass to Tornado's websocket handler.)

Now, whenever we do a long ( > 6) asyncio.sleep in our code, our websocket disconnects, while regular time.sleep does not disconnect it. Obviously, it seems the websocket ping interval does not play nice with asyncio.sleep.

What should we change to fix this?
(Assuming we still need the total of 6 seconds to detect disconnections.)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? As I used and tested, everything seems to be ok, `asyncio.sleep` does not "disconnect" clients.

Comment: You need to create your websocket handler with the described parameters to make sure it checks the ping keepalive. Then when you asyncio.sleep(), the keepalive will fail and the connection will be closed.

I'm sorry for not providing a better example, but it's 2am here, and I've been testing & fixing bugs since 5am, gonna go crash, it's been a long day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that frame processing in Tornado is done sequentially, which means that pings will not be handled in time if a different message is being handled for a very long time.

We've opened an issue in the Tornado GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2941).